# htaccess restricts the bootstrap file I'm calling

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, twitter-bootstrap

I have an include folder which also contains the bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js in the directory `localhost/project/include`. My `localhost/project/index.php` or simply `localhost/project` is a login form that I created which calls the designs rom the `localhost/project/include`. My htaccess located in `localhost/project/include` has a `deny from all`. But the problem is that if I try to call the link and scripts through `link href` and `script src`, htaccess blocks it which makes my login page look horrid.

Comment: As of the moment, my only remedy is to rename the include folder to something like `fj8914efyh7981fajk8` so that people can't possibly guess the include directory and to add an .htaccess that restricts index listing just in case.

Comment: Why are the Bootstrap files in your include directory? And why not just link to Bootstrap with one of the CDNs available?

Comment: I like to keep everything I call in the include directory, I plan to use this system only on LAN

Comment: But Bootstrap isn't an "include" in the same sense as your PHP files. do you plan to keep your images in there too?

Comment: Yes to the image part, but it seems like you're right, it really makes sense to just put php files on the include but where should I put my css/bootstrap files so they can't be accessed directly?

Comment: I tried using the `Options -Indexes` on the htaccess and it displays an Access forbidden! page when I'm on the `localhost/include/`. But the flaw here is that if the user knew the exact file, they would still be able to open it.